# Running Python Script inside AWS RDS

Tags: python, sql-server, amazon-web-services, ssis

We have an SSIS Project on our local server. Somewhere in the project there is a `Process Task` which calls a python script on the server which runs a machine learning project to make some prediction based on data in the SQL Server database.
Now we want to migrate this local SSIS Project onto AWS. The problem is that according to the [supported tasks in AWS SSIS on RDS](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/Appendix.SQLServer.Options.SSIS.html) Process Task is not supported. Our Process Task (which calls the python script) is between other tasks which are dependent on the Python process.
One option is to use AWS Glue instead of SSIS which is not an option for us as it requires much development effort as our SSIS project is quite huge.
Another option is to use AWS Lambda for the Python Task, but as I said the python process task is located between other tasks in SSIS and the other tasks depend on the python task and should not run before the Python Process Task is finished. So the only solution that comes into my mind is the following:

1. Migrate the SSIS packages (minus the Process Task) into AWS.
2. Create an AWS Lambda which calls the Python script.
3. When the SSIS control flow reaches the point where the python package should be called, somehow the AWS Lambda is triggered.
4. The SSIS control flow remains in a loop which looks for a flag in the database.
5. After AWS Lambda is finished, the flag in db is set.
6. The SSIS control flow exits the loop and continues with the remaining tasks.

Is there a better solution for this problem? Is this solution correct?

Comment: I don't AWS but I do know a bit about SSIS. Given the parameters you've supplied, you have 2 SSIS packages. Everything Before the Process Activity and Everything After. The total job stream is: EB runs, Lambda runs, EA runs. Whether whatever AWS scheduling provides can accomplish this is unknown.  And since Script Task is also not supported, there goes option 2 of using the .NET library to run the python. Seems like SSIS is not a great fit for AWS for your use case based on the limitations they document

Comment: @billinkc the issues only exist if you use SQL Server RDS. Installing SQL Server on an EC2 instance does not have all the limitations. They even sell EC2 instances that already have SQL Server loaded on to them and the pricing is actually better.

Comment: @CodePope I would still use a .NET solution here. You should have access to an APP server (probably where SSRS reports are deployed to) where you can put a console app that is solely a go between to Start a Process and Wait for completion. You can call it through a job --- Step 1 run SSIS A step 2 run console using powershell (allowing you to run it on another server) step 3 Run SSIS B

Comment: @KeithL thanks for the response. Your option is definitely worth trying. Regarding your point of using EC2 instance instead of RDS: The main reason using RDS over EC2 is that the patching AND DBA stuff is done by AWS completely.

Comment: I think you might want to do the whole process in .NET if you go this route and call jobs via SQL so that you can ensure that the process finishes. this link shows you how to do this. https://masudprogrammer.wordpress.com/2016/08/31/ssis-execute-a-pacakge-and-wait-until-package-execution-finished/